# Matplotlib scatterplot with standardized colormap across subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, colorbar, scatter

I Have two sets of data that I would like to compare. Each set of data has x and y values along with some z values for each x,y point. The distribution of z values between the two data sets may overlap each other, but generally will have portions that do not overlap. In this case [1,4] and [2,6]. I would like for the color scheme to take this into account so I can visualize these differences when comparing the two sets. I would eventually like to use a colorbar added to this figure as well.
Some example code:

```
# Fake Values
vals1 = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,4]])
vals2 = np.array([[1,1,2],[2,2,6]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, constrained_layout=True)
g1 = ax[0].scatter(x=vals1[:,0], y=vals1[:,1], c=vals1[:,2], cmap='RdBu')
g2 = ax[1].scatter(x=vals2[:,0], y=vals2[:,1], c=vals2[:,2], cmap='RdBu')
fig.colorbar(g2)
```

This gives me the following:

[image: Scatterplot with bad color scheme]

As you can see the z (c?) values are not standardized between the subplots.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `vmin`/`vmax` of both plots as the data's global min/max.

Either set the `vmin`/`vmax` params individually:

```py
vmin = np.vstack([vals1,vals2]).min()
vmax = np.vstack([vals1,vals2]).max()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, constrained_layout=True)
g1 = ax[0].scatter(x=vals1[:,0], y=vals1[:,1], c=vals1[:,2], vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cmap='RdBu')
g2 = ax[1].scatter(x=vals2[:,0], y=vals2[:,1], c=vals2[:,2], vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cmap='RdBu')
fig.colorbar(g2)
```

Or create a [**`matplotlib.colors.Normalize()`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize) instance and use it for the `norm` param:

```py
norm = mcolors.Normalize(
    vmin=np.vstack([vals1,vals2]).min(),
    vmax=np.vstack([vals1,vals2]).max(),
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, constrained_layout=True)
g1 = ax[0].scatter(x=vals1[:,0], y=vals1[:,1], c=vals1[:,2], norm=norm, cmap='RdBu')
g2 = ax[1].scatter(x=vals2[:,0], y=vals2[:,1], c=vals2[:,2], norm=norm, cmap='RdBu')
fig.colorbar(g2)
```

[image: synced vmin/vmax]

Comment: You can also create the `Norm` outside of the call to scatter and pass it to both of them.

Comment: Hi @tdy and thanks for your reply! It looks like there was typo in my original code which was recapitualted in your reply. If you change the c value in the g2 line to: c=vals2[:,2] it will be correct!